# Select2 initial tags

Tags: jquery-select2

I have been having this issue in `select2`. I cannot show the initial tags, as shown in `select2`'s home page:

```
<input width="100px" type="text" id="e12">
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
 $("#e12").select2({multiple:'true',tags:["red", "green", "blue"]});
 });
</script>
```

But the "colors" are shown if and only if I begin typing. Otherwise, the input is blank.

Answer (score 1):

As simple as the hot water: I forgot to put the value in the input tag!

```
 <input width="100px" type="text" id="e12" value="pippo,italy">
```